# 8 bit string presentation on a label output

Tags: swift, macos, utf-8, label, byte

Swift2 label utf8 error?

I am using copy and paste to transfer coded 8 bit string data from a database to a Swift2 OSX program. The input is OK (label.stringValue) but I can't get the output to label correctly.

It seems if the msb (most significant bit) is 1 the label.stringValue presents 2 bytes even though the input is Utf8 (1 byte unsigned)

Can anyone assist in having a label.stringValue output that is able to present all 256 possible byte options in a one byte output format?

Thanks in advance,

Erik

Comment: check how UTF-8 coding works http://www.wikiwand.com/en/UTF-8

Comment: understood, my bad. the question remains: is there a way to use all 8 bits of a byte and display that in swift 2?

Comment: ok, lets have one byte, which value can be 0x00 ... 0xff. what kind of representation do you expect in label.stringValue ??  what type is your label instance? what type is label.stringValue ? (NSTextView, or your own implementation ?)

Comment: Thanks so far for your input, your answer made me realise perhaps my copy/paste idea from database to program is not a good way. The MsSQL database lets me copy the content (936 bytes of data) and I can paste it into a text field. However after calculations i would like to have only 1 byte presentation of each byte. I use to print  Swift.print(" lengte \(allebits.utf8.count) met waarde: \(UInt8(bytewaarde)) ")

Comment: Sorry I did exceed my comment time: the conversion from byte to string I use is: returnString += convertToCharacters(UInt8Bits: eachUInt8Byte) which gives me the problem. I think I should find another way, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: erik, that is, why you have to read what does it mean 'character'. 'character set', utf-8 coding etc. there are a lot of single byte values, which can't be recognized as 'character'. in utf-8 coding, one single 'character; can be represented by the sentence of bytes (one to six maximum). check the link from my very first note again and see, that you are NOT able represent any single byte value as 'character'. in ASCII coding there are just 127 'characters' etc.